# mongoose push result to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I was trying to get a result from my MongoDB in a for loop by using a mongoose "findOne" and then push the results into an array. The found result is always correct, but it doesn't pushes it into my array, it stays empty all time. I tried it with promises, so use a then after the findOne like

```
Company.findOne().exec(...).then(function(val){
    //here comes then the push function
});
```

but that also returned an empty array. Now my code looks like this:

```
var Company = require('../app/models/company');


function findAllComps(){
    var complist = [];

    for (var i = 0, l = req.user.companies.length; i < l; i++) {
        var compid = req.user.companies[i];

        Company.findOne({id: compid}, function(err, company){
            if(err)
                return console.log(err);

            if (company !== null)
                //result is an object
                complist.push(company);
        });
    }
    return complist;
}

res.json(findAllComps());
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: use `async` or `promises`

Comment: how should it look like? As I said I tried it with a "then" after the execution but that also didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `req.user.companies` is an array of IDs, you can simply use the [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to find all companies having any of the IDs.

```
// find all companies with the IDs given
Company.find({ id: { $in: req.user.companies }}, function (err, companies) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    // note: you must wait till the callback is called to send back your response
    res.json({ companies: companies });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me and it's pretty simple, thank you! :)